# Digitally signed msi with limited user upgrade still prompt for administrator

Tags: c#, wix, windows-installer, digital-certificate

i am working around this for a while now and wasn't able to figure that out.
i prepared a msi (using wix) which is with install scope = perMachine and InstallPrivileges=elevated.

the application has only an exe file.
both exe and msi are signed by a certificate.

i install the application with a limited user (on windows 7) and it prompts for an administrator user and password.

i created an upgrade for the application.
when i install it i expected it just to install because of the digital signature.
but it keeps prompting for an administrator password.

i am really lost here,
would love some help.
thanks

Answer (score 2):

Every time you execute an application that requires elevated privileges, UAC (User Account Control, added in Vista) requires an administrator username and password to grant the elevated privileges.  These privileges last only as long as the operation takes, and must be re-granted every time they are requested, even for the same program.

Comment: thanks for the reply, is there a way i can make the update run for a limited user? i read that there is a way to grant permissions by the administrator to the application and if it is signed than the limited user can also run the update. (i think that chrome does that).

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for UAC Patching http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372388.aspx

Comment: this is relevant only for msp files, right? can this be done for msi files?

Comment: @user1252847 The only method I know is to enable ["Always install with elevated privileges"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms813108.aspx), yet it's not recommended because of security. Using Group Policy, administrator can advertise packages which can then be installed without elevation prompt. I cannot find references to confirm this.